# Default SQL Server for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two instances of SQL Server - `SQLEXPRESS` and `MSSQLServer 2017`. My Entity Framework test application creates database in `SQLEXPRESS`. Where is it defined which instance of SQL Server Entity Framework should use?

Test application:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class PeopleContext : DbContext
    {
        public IDbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) // using DB
    {
        try
        {
            using (PeopleContext ctx = new PeopleContext())
            {
                ctx.People.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe" });
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (PeopleContext ctx = new PeopleContext())
            {
                Person person = ctx.People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
                Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("finish");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

UPD:
I have several connection strings in my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="LearnCSharpConn_server" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=LearnCSharp;Integrated Security=True" />
    <add name="LearnCSharpConn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LearnCSharp.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

How EF decides which one to use?

Comment: I have several of connection strings. How EF decides which one to use? More details in UPD.

Comment: @Vico: If it has chosen SQL Express with non concrete DbContext it is probably chooses SQL Express as default. MSDN, “If you don't specify a connection string, Entity Framework will create a LocalDB database in the users directory with the fully qualified name of the DbContext class”. See end of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string.

Comment: @HugoUchoBruno Nevermind, the user deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
public class PeopleContext : DbContext
{
    public PeopleContext() : base("Database") //it makes reference to the connection string defined in the app.config
    {     
    }
    public IDbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

And in your app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Database" connectionString="Data Source=source;Initial Catalog=Your_database;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To discover the `server`, `username`, `password` and `default database` you should seek to find the connection string being used by **Entity Framework.**

You do not specify which version of **Entity framework** you use, however most versions store the connection string in either `web.config` or `app.config`.

Alternatively, you may step into the `PeopleContext` constructor via Visual Studio's debug mode to view a connection string, or in **.Net Core** the connection string can be found by stepping through the `OnConfigure` method in `PeopleContext.cs`.

Failing that you may `Ctrl + f` to search `connectionString` over entire solution.